# How to display values of an associative array with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, foreach, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an `array` which is:

[image]

And I want to make a foreach loop and list all `key's` & `script_content's` to the view.

My vue components mounted method:

```
mounted() {
        this.loading = true;
        axios.get('/app/json-ld/json-ld-settings')
            .then(res => {
                let data = res.data;
                console.log(data.scripts);
                this.key = data.scripts[0]['key'];
                this.scriptContent = data.scripts[0]['script_content'];
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.loading = false;

                this.$notify({
                    group: 'notify',
                    type: 'error',
                    text: 'Something happened! Please refresh the page and try again or contact support!',
                });
            });
    },
```

component data:

```
data: () => ({
        errors: {},
        key: [],
        scriptContent: [],
```

I am able to display the values of the first array, but don't know how to make a foreach loop in an associative array.

HTML:

```
    <div class="py-3 d-flex flex-row justify-content-end align-content-end">
        <div class="pr-2">
            <h5>Key</h5>
            <span>{{key}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="pl-2">
            <h5>Script content</h5>
            <span>{{scriptContent}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The goal is to list all `key's` and `script_content's` in a HTML list or a div.

Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should store all scripts into the data, not just `data.scripts[0]`, and then iterate over them in the template using `v-for` directive. Here is a couple of good examples:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Answer (score 1):

You can just use codes below:

```
data() {
   return {
     keys: [],
     contents: [],
   }
}

...
for (let index in data) {
   this.keys.push(data[index].key);
   this.contents.push(data[index].script_content);
}
...
```

Then you can use v-for in html codes to use keys and contents.

Comment: Thanks. Where this `for` statement should be placed? 
In mounted method?

Comment: @ViktorasssIT Yes, you can place it in mounted method.

Comment: Thanks, but the solution was this:
this.scripts.forEach(function (script) {

                    });